# SQL Server 2014 - Errog log from Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, etl, error-log

I have been tasked to try and automate a process using SQL of taking a .bak file and importing in to SQL, manipulating the data to push the data back out to Access (this is a temporary measure while we come away from Access).

Part of this process involves excluding fields from the data and also a bit of data cleansing.  I will also need to create an 'error log' for each of the tables to show which records have been excluded.

I have a reporting background, so doing this kind of work is very new to me and I am slowly working my way around it but I was wondering if I am doing things correctly or if there is a better way to do this.

I am basically using 'restore database' to bring in the .bak file in a database I have created, then using this database, I am writing select statements to take pick up the relevant fields and then putting these into a new database and then this will be exported to Access.

I can probably create another select statement that is the opposite of the statement used to pull the date (so IS NULL rather than IS NOT NULL etc) but I'm assuming there must be a simpler, cleaner way of doing things.

Any advice you have would be gratefully received.  I have spend the past few weeks living on Google trying to work it all out.

Thanks for your time, Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **EXCEPT** keyword or **NOT EXISTS** to select the rows which exist in the first database but not the second, alternatively doing as you think (inverting any filters) would also work - although be more error prone.

Comment: Hi Milney - Thanks for your response.  I wasn't aware that either keyword existed (no pun intended) so I will take a look and see what magic they can perform :)